# The Largest Prime Less Than the Square of a Prime

Tags: prime-numbers

The first prime is two. Two squared is four. The largest prime that is less than four is three.

The set of primes is 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31...

The set of their squares is 4,9,25,49,121,169,289,361,529,841,961...

The set of numbers which I am asking about is 3,7,23,47,113,167,283,359,523,839,953...

Has this particular set of numbers been studied before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my question is no.

I very strongly believe this sequence to be of more importance than mathematicians realize. If there are no papers yet written about it, then perhaps its importance is not yet known. I have begun writing a book that will reveal a deep relationship between this sequence and the distribution of the primes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this sequence is so important? That would be interesting to read.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I am planning to write a book about this because the information takes up so much space.

Answer (score 2):

Its [OEIS A054270](https://oeis.org/A054270). Which would suggest "yes" to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes.](https://oeis.org/A054270)

Next time you are wondering whether a sequence of integers has been considered before, look it up on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: It is listed as A054270. But I can't see that it has been "studied"? I cannot find any  reference to a paper there.

Comment: If the sequence had been studied further, I would imagine there would be mention of it in the OEIS. Certainly it has been "noted" before.

Comment: Note also sequence [A054271](https://oeis.org/A054271).